# Spring MVC dynamically ignore or drop requests

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Consider, as an example, the following Spring controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    private boolean dropRequest = false;

    /* Any GET requests to /timeout?dropRequest=true (or false)
     * will set the dropRequest field
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/timeout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public void responseTimeout(@RequestParam(value = "dropRequest", required = true, defaultValue = "false") final boolean dropRequest) {
        this.dropRequest = dropRequest;
    }

    /* Perform or ignore a request depending on value of 'dropRequest' */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/updatedata", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public UpdatedDataObj requestUpdate(@RequestBody final String data) {
        if (this.dropRequest) {
            // drop/ignore request (do nothing, let it timeout, don't send a 404 or 500)
        } else {
            // process request as normal
        }
    }
}
```

I have a web page with a checkbox which, when checked, sends a `GET` to `/timeout` as above.  This sets the `dropRequest` field to true.  I now want any subsequent `POST`s to `/updatedata` to be dropped/ignored.  I don't want a 500/404 response, I want the client to timeout waiting on a response.  I was wondering how this can be achieved in Spring MVC?  I have searched a little on this, I see one way to approach it would be to have an interceptor? Would that work?  I don't like the idea of putting in a `sleep(N)` before returning in the controller to force a timeout.

**Edit:** I applied an Interceptor as suggested below.  I am getting a 200 OK response from the request when I expected it to time out.

```
public class TestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler)
        throws Exception {
        if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
            HandlerMethod hm = (HandlerMethod) handler;
            String methodName = hm.getMethod().getName();
            if (methodName.equals("requestUpdate")) {
                Object obj = hm.getBean();
                if (obj instanceof MyController) {
                    MyController controller = (MyController) obj;

                    /* I added responsesDisabled() method to controller
                     * to return the boolean disabled field
                     */
                    return !controller.responsesDisabled();
                }
            }
        } 
        return true;
    }
}
```

And I added the following into the xml:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.blah.interceptors.TestInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

So if I `POST` to `/requestUpdate` the `preHandle()` method is executed as expected.  However, this does not time out the response.  I receive an empty 200 OK.  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see a lot of ways to do a timeout other than waiting doing nothing.

Comment: please can you post the steps you have done for overcome from this issue.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Interceptors.

step1 : create an interceptor class which implements HandlerInterceptor and override its methods.

Step 2 : inside preHandle() method write your logic to get the checkbox value and check it with if condition, if its checked then return true from this method to continue the flow and if its unchecked return false from this method to discontinue the flow.

let me know for any issues.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not timing out.  I am getting a 200OK response.  I will edit my post above to provide more details.

Comment: I am using interceptor for handling only public site request but interceptor preventing css stuff to load, it assume that css path as request. How to handle that in preHandle() method ?